# Create MessageBox With TextBox In It

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I create a messagebox with two textboxes inside of it so the user can type in information that I can save?

Answer (score 9):

Make a custom form and call `MyForm.ShowDialog()`, assuming you have the dialog results set up properly.

Answer (score 3):

The built-in MessageBox does not support that. You need create your own window and show in modal mode (setting the owner property)